# Get URLs of resolved dependencies with gradle

Tags: java, maven, gradle

When you first resolve dependencies with gradle it generally spits out to the console what the url of the resolved dependency was (for example using if using mavenCentral() as the repository it will print out the URL to the maven central repo it resolved the dependency from).

Is there a way to to do this without removing the cache and re-resolving the dependency?

Thanks!

Comment: In theory it might be possible since Maven seems to store repository urls in some "internal" files like `artifact.lastUpdated` or `_maven.repositories` and the artifact url could be reconstructed using those as well as artifact information. However, the question would be: why should a build system expose that to the user via some api?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58748741/6412910